# How to generate an ID in Oracle?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I want to create sql queries to insert data in my Oracle database.

I blocked on the ID part, on my JAVA code, I generate Ids like this.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
protected String id;
```

But I don't know how to do it in SQL.

Thank you!

Comment: Use [sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314)

Comment: Never use `UUID` as keys in a database if you do not have to; if you are forced to use them do not wonder about performance.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason you're doing this on the java side ? This is something that the database will handle more efficient. If this is a new table and you have the choice I would do this with an `identity column` in your table.

For example (this solution will do just fine in 99% of the cases):

```
create table test_tab 
  (id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY 
       CONSTRAINT test_tab_pk PRIMARY KEY
   column1 VARCHAR2(10)
  );
```

Alternatively, if you want generate an id based on a guid, you could use the following syntax. Note that here the id column is still a number - the format mask X converts it to the hexadecimal value.

```
CREATE TABLE test_tab (
  id NUMBER DEFAULT ON NULL to_number(sys_guid(),'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
    CONSTRAINT test_tab_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  column1  VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
);
```

Or, if it *has* to be a guid, then you could define your primary key column as a VARCHAR2 and store the actual guid. Note that this is not a best practice.

```
CREATE TABLE test_tab (
  id VARCHAR2(50) default on null sys_guid()
    CONSTRAINT test_tab_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  column1  VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
);
```

In the insert statement you can just leave the id column out, it will be populated automatically.

`INSERT INTO test_tab(column1) VALUES ('Foobar');`

Comment: As I understand the question, the table sues UUIDs/GUIDs for teh ID column, nut integers!

Comment: Updated my answers. From the question I assumed that the database knowledge of the poster is rather basic and most probably he's just trying to get a proper key in which case a sequence will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the Oracle function `SYS_GUID()` in the insert statement for your `ID` column.